# Unable to run headless selenium on heroku with javascript enabled

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, heroku, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to scrape some twitter data with headless selenium running in a Spring Boot application on Heroku. The following 2 buildpacks are included in my Heroku app:

1) https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver.git

2) https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome.git

These two buildpacks are designed for running headless selenium in a heroku app. 
After the selenium script enters my twitter login data and hit the login button, my script keeps crashing. Why? I examined the page source and found the following hint from twitter:

> **We've detected that JavaScript is disabled in your browser. Would you**
>   **like to proceed to legacy Twitter?**

So obviously javascript seems to be disabled which is very bad. And i don't want to proceed in legacy mode (without javascript).

When initializing the webdriver, i tried the following two options to make sure javascript is enabled. But it seems to be ignored:

Option 1)

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless", "--enable-javascript");
WebDriver webdriver =  ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Option 2)

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
WebDriver webdriver =  ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved it by removing some options.

This is my driver options (python) currently:

```
options = Options()
options.binary_location = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=os.getenv("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"))
```